# Qt widgets 4.7 vs. 5.1

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt5

I recently started on a new project where we will be using Qt to create the GUI. Without getting into details, it has been mandated by management that we use Qt 4.7. There are no valid reasons for this decision. We are not porting any existing code to Qt 5, this is all new implementation. I am the UI lead for the project and I need to make a case for using Qt 5.1.

I am going to explain why the concerns held by some of the engineers about moving to 5.1 are not legitimate, but I would also like to strengthen my case by giving specific reasons that we should use Qt 5.1 over 4.7. My main reason behind wanting to use 5.1 is just that it's the latest version with many improvements over 4.7. While this reason is valid, I would appreciate it if anybody who is familiar with the differences between Qt 4.7+ compared to 5.0+ would help me come up with some specific reasons. I have not used Qt 5 yet myself. We will be using widgets either way, not QtQuick/QML, so please only consider differences pertaining to Qt widgets.

Comment: Going to Qt's website [**reveals this**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/whatsnew.html). Most notable seem to be "Compile-time Checks for Signal-slot Connections" and the various new OpenGL hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt 5.1 has several new features over Qt 4.7 or 4.8. One of the important ones I guess is the new syntax for signals and slots which will provide:

1. Compile time check of the existence of the signals and slot, of the types, or if the Q_OBJECT is missing which means you will get a compiler error if you misspelled the signal or slot name, or if the arguments of your slot do not match those from the signal. This might save you some time while you are doing some re-factoring and change the name or arguments of signals or slots.
2. Possibility to connect to any member function of QObject, not only slots.
3. The new syntax can even connect to functions, not just QObjects.

It also provides some new support for C++11

For more check these:

http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html

http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html